# PSTricks: Dataplot

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\savedata{\data}[{1999,6276},{2000,6827},{2001,7783},{2002,9819}]
\psset{xAxisLabel={Year},yAxisLabel={Ocapi}}
\begin{psgraph}[Ox=1999,xlabelOffset=0.5,Dy=2000]{->}(1999,0)(2004,13000){13.5cm}{8.1cm}
\dataplot[plotstyle=dots,dotstyle=o,fillcolor=red]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

I tried to re-use [this answer](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22086#p74393) from Herbert but it is not working. The error is

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pst@xunit 

l.8 ...000]{->}(1999,0)(2004,13000){13.5cm}{8.1cm}
```

If I can get a solution and an explanation as to why it is not working, I would be greatful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run with any compiler:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xtick={1999,...,2002},
    ymin=0
]
\addplot +[only marks] table{
1999 6276
2000 6827
2001 7783
2002 9819
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(with a wink and nod to Herbert)

---

With `pst-plot`, you need to shift your coordinates manually before you can plot them. You do this by adding

```
\pstScalePoints(1,1){1999 sub}{}
```

which subtracts 1999 from all your x coordinates. If you then adjust your plot limits to range from x=0 to 5 and use `\listplot` instead of `\dataplot`, you get the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\savedata{\data}[{1999,6276},{2000,6827},{2001,7783},{2002,9819}]
\pstScalePoints(1,1){1999 sub}{}
\psset{xAxisLabel={Year},yAxisLabel={Ocapi}}
\begin{psgraph}[Ox=1999,xlabelOffset=0.5,Dy=2000]{->}(0,0)(5,13000){13.5cm}{8.1cm}
\listplot[plotstyle=dots,dotstyle=o,fillcolor=red]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jake. I will be glad if the plot can be made with `pst-plot` but if I don't get an PSTricks answer, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @SvendMortensen: I figured out the PSTricks issue: `pst-plot` doesn't internally rescale the data like PGFPlots does, which is why you get the `dimension too large` errors. You need to manually shift your data first. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\savedata{\data}[{1999,6276},{2000,6827},{2001,7783},{2002,9819}]
\psset{xAxisLabel=Year,yAxisLabel=Ocapi}
\begin{psgraph}[Ox=1999,xlabelOffset=0.5,Dy=2000]{->}(0,0)(5,13000){10cm}{6cm}
\pstScalePoints(1,1){ 1999 sub }{}
\listplot[showpoints,linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and Jake's? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: using showpoints instead of setting dots _and_ a line

Comment: @SvendMortensen: I don't see. Where did I set a line in the PSTricks approach?

Comment: @Jake. I looked at the `pst-plot` code instead of the `pgfplots` code. Sorry. (Maybe Herbert did the same thing.)